# Combobox width resizing issue, when added as a column to edit data in ListView control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have followed the below link to use a ComboBox control to edit the data in a ListView control and I have succeeded in doing that.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320344

But the issue is my comobox width is getting out of the ListView control when a Horizontal scrollbar comes up because the ComboBox is not physically part of the ListView control and the ComboBox does not automatically scroll with the ListView.

Here I need to find the Visible Width of the column which holds the combox & set this width to my Combobox width.

P.S.  In the url above, its clearly mentioned that for positioning and sizing the ComboBox, this sample also watches for two messages on the ListView control: WM_VSCROLL and WM_HSCROLL. This works as the focus is moved to ListVew from Combobox when scrolling is done. But when clicked on any ListViewItem from next time, the explained issue happens.

Can anyone suggest me how can I proceed for this issue.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to work with the TableLayoutPanel to get more opportunities for the future and does not spend time on this.